# How to insert rows requiring the encryption method used in this example?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I am working with a MySql database for which the client side code is unavailable to me.

I need to insert many more rows in a table in bulk, rather than manually through the client.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `__Auth` (
  `doctype` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fieldname` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `encrypted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doctype`,`name`,`fieldname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

A valid insert command looks like this...

```sql
INSERT INTO `_a7a7e96ba1644fd9`.`__Auth` (doctype,name,fieldname,password,encrypted) VALUES 
(
   'Email Account',
   'John Smith',
   'password',
   'gAAAAABd46ytFrw8sNGQf9-kk0q3qc9ozKw1aF5OyFtF31qxLm4WK9iWXC-H-uWRsUCPW_QUFe8dhYu0C3D6Nd36dlTLb1EuYiQkHt6-aJHSv_fZ77w2knA=',
   1
);
```

I have the encryption key.  It looks like this...
  *`FwCG-MUY37j6Qqqzm_Z-kkXkHwiO1y09tg6QNhZVuXg=`*
... however, my problem is that **I need to generate the encrypted password string in my insert statements!**

I have tried using inserts replacing the password field with, for example...

```sql
AES_ENCRYPT('qtgkskwqroqjrewq','FwCG-MUY37j6Qqqzm_Z-kkXkHwiO1y09tg6QNhZVuXg=')
```

... but, because the output looks like this *',ÈÚ:!¼ ÷X ©u¯r@÷S¦ã©pv'* I get an `SQL Error [1366] [22007]: (conn=794) Incorrect string value`.

Since the encrypted password looks a lot like a short RSA public key I tried...

```sql
SELECT FROM_BASE64('gAAAAABd46ytFrw8sNGQf9-kk0q3qc9ozKw1aF5OyFtF31qxLm4WK9iWXC-H-uWRsUCPW_QUFe8dhYu0C3D6Nd36dlTLb1EuYiQkHt6-aJHSv_fZ77w2knA=');
```

... but the result is `null`.

**Questions**

1) How can I build an insert command with MySql functions that use a key like this...

*'FwCG-MUY37j6Qqqzm_Z-kkXkHwiO1y09tg6QNhZVuXg='*

... to turn this text...

*'qtgkskwqroqjrewq'*

... into this text ...

*'gAAAAABd46ytFrw8sNGQf9-kk0q3qc9ozKw1aF5OyFtF31qxLm4WK9iWXC-H-uWRsUCPW_QUFe8dhYu0C3D6Nd36dlTLb1EuYiQkHt6-aJHSv_fZ77w2knA='*

??

2) Does my database connection &/or INSERT statement have to specify *utf8mb4_unicode_ci* while I try to use AES_ENCRYPT();

3) Am I attempting the impossible??

Comment: You don't have enough information here - a key and examples of plaintext and ciphertext is a good start - but not enough to determine the algorithm, block mode, IV/nonce handling etc...  There are a lot of moving parts to this.  Consult the client code - or the person/team who wrote it.  Without knowing, at the very least, what algorithm was used, you can't do much.

Comment: I have been Googling for half a day trying to find any of the information you suggest.  I am assuming standard MySql functions were used.  I may be wrong.  I am hoping someone will recognize the method used.

Comment: You can't "recognize" the result of an encryption operation - that is the point.  Any modern encryption algorithm produces an output that is indistinguishable from random noise.  Your assumption could be completely wrong - how do you know the encryption was performed in MySQL as compared to some application code using xyz cryptography library?

Comment: You are quite correct, of course.  But there is a short list of MySql standard password encryption methods that do have recognizable output.

Comment: "Password encryption" is a bit of a misnomer - you're likely talking about password hashing functions like bcrypt, argon2 etc.  These are often represented in a format that is recognizable, yes.  Encryption is something else - which is something you really need to determine - is this hashing or is it encryption?

Comment: As mentioned -- I have an encryption key from a config file.

Comment: There are keyed hash functions.  We can continue back and forth but the truth is you are lacking enough information to really solve this.  Is it not possible to view the original code or at least get in touch with the original developer?